# Forbidden Error 403 On Server Folder

Tags: php, server, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to host a new blog where I can add posts using a simple HTML form & PHP script.  When I test out the form on my localhost everything works fine, but when I upload it and test it live I get:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /php/add-post.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I know that my host allows this type of script because I'm using exactly the same thing on another blog, and my permissions are set to `0755`.  Does anyone know what the problem might be & how to solve it?

Comment: And what's the permission setting for the directory "php/" ?

Comment: Like I said `0755`!!!

Comment: Is php/ underneath DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: I don't quite understand! I have `http://website.com/php/add-post.php` on the form so it should link to this location anyway

Comment: Add your current apache config file !

Comment: Are you using TLS (https) on your live site after developing with http?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in .htaccess file

```
<Files add-post.php>
Order Deny,Allow 
Deny from all
Allow from all
</Files>
```

Or run command to provide permission to folder

`chmod 774 /path/to/php/add-post.php`