# Reasons For A Forbidden Error 403 When File Exists

Tags: php

I have a blog with a Post upload form using PHP.  I've tested it on my localhost and everything works perfectly.  When I upload the exact same website onto my hosting account and try to add a post, I'm given a Forbidden Error 403 message:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /php/add-post.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Now, if the form and script exist and work on my localhost, surely they should exist on the live server, and should work in exactly the same way.  Are there any particular reasons why I could be getting this Forbidded Error & 404 Error?

--

.htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex posts.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    

RewriteRule ^posts/([0-9]+)/?$              posts.php?currentpage=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^section/([\w-]+)/?$            section.php?section=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^section/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$   section.php?section=$1&currentpage=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^posts/([\w-]+)/?$              posts.php?category=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^posts/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$     posts.php?category=$1&currentpage=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)/?$      post.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^sites/([0-9]+)/?$              sites.php?currentpage=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^posts posts.php
RewriteRule ^section section.php
RewriteRule ^sites sites.php

RewriteRule ^about about.php
RewriteRule ^advertise advertise.php
RewriteRule ^subscribe subscribe.php
```

Comment: what's the file permission of the file?

Comment: The permission is 0644

Comment: try changing it to 0755 or 0777. it should probably work on 0755

Comment: please also add your `.htaccess` to the code, if you have one.

Comment: Sorry @roullie, but that has made no difference.  My other blogs are working fine on 0644

Comment: Added that @SeseSchneider

Comment: @FootBlogger there is no error in `.htaccess` which can cause your problem.

Comment: is there another `.htaccess` in the subdir php?

Comment: Yeah thanks for that @SeseSchneider, so what is the problem?  I've just tested this again on my local server and it's working completely fine.  Any other ideas?  No other .htaccess exists in that directory

Comment: Check your filepermissions. `chmod 0755 php/add-post.php`

Comment: I already did that @SeseSchneider.  Was on 0644 (Same as my other working blogs) and changed it to 0755.  That had no effect.

Comment: @FootBlogger i think this could be a server error. Check you `apache configs`, maybe recreate folders with root ownership.

Comment: Sorry @SeseSchneider, but how do I do that on CPanel X3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forbidden Error 403 On Server Folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267392/forbidden-error-403-on-server-folder)