# Irrational Forbidden 403 Error Message

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a blog with a `add-post.php` page which contains a simple form with the action:

```
<form id="form" action="add-post-php.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I then have the file, `add-post-php.php` in the same folder as `add-form.php`.  So I enter the details of my blog into the form and press submit and get:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /add-post-php.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I've tested this on my localhost and it works correctly, the permission of the file is set at 0644, but I've also tried it at 0755, with no improvement.  There is nothing wrong with my .htaccess file and there are no other .htaccess files in the directory.

My `add-post-php.php` script in full is:

```
<?php
include("php/settings.php"); // Contains DB Connections
?>
<?php
$id= time();
$month = date("m");
$year = date("Y");
$path = "images/posts/$year/$month/";

$section = $_POST["section"];
$category = $_POST["category"];
$credit = $_POST["credit"];
$title = ucwords($_POST["title"]);
$text = $_POST["text"];
$exclusive = $_POST["exclusive"];

$added = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$photo = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
$ext = substr(strrchr($photo, '.'), 1);
?>
<?php
$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO posts (id, section, category, credit, title, article, exclusive, added) VALUES('$id', '$section', '$category', '$credit', '$title', '$text', '$exclusive', '$added')";
$insert_res = mysqli_query($con, $insert_sql);
if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0){
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],"$path" . $id . "." . $ext);
}
else{
echo "0";
exit();
};
?>
<?php
header("Location: post.php?id=$id");
exit();
?>
```

Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting the Forbidden Error when the file clearly exists and it's permissions are correct?

Here is my .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex posts.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    

RewriteRule ^posts/([0-9]+)/?$              posts.php?currentpage=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^section/([\w-]+)/?$            section.php?section=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^section/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$   section.php?section=$1&currentpage=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^posts/([\w-]+)/?$              posts.php?category=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^posts/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$     posts.php?category=$1&currentpage=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)/?$      post.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^sites/([0-9]+)/?$              sites.php?currentpage=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^posts posts.php
RewriteRule ^section section.php
RewriteRule ^sites sites.php

RewriteRule ^about about.php
RewriteRule ^advertise advertise.php
RewriteRule ^subscribe subscribe.php
```

Folder structure:

[image]

I've just checked the php error log again and I'm seeing these messages:

> [Thu Oct 22 13:04:14.575567 2015] [:error] [pid 1041578] [client 74.125.76.51:56087] File does not exist: /home/fulldist/public_html/***.com/feed.php,
>
> [Thu Oct 22 09:53:14.646744 2015] [:error] [pid 944286] [client 31.13.113.90:59997] File does not exist: /home/fulldist/public_html/***.com/blog.php.

It's true that feed.php and blog.php don't exist, but why is it trying to look them up?

Comment: Try to put the full path in the action attribute.

Comment: Thanks @Daan but I already tried that one yesterday and had the exact same problem

Comment: Can you show your directory structure?

Comment: Have you got an `.htaccess` file that might be doing something odd

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Not that I can see, I've added my htaccess code above

Comment: @Daan - I've added a screenshot of my folder structure!

Comment: File permissions are usually an OS thing - but you've provided no details of the OS. Assuming this is Linux, you might want to check for FACLs (getfacl)  or SELinux labels (ls -Z).

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I assume you have checked the `php error log` and the `apache access log`

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Yes I've checked the `php error log` and there's nothing out of the ordinary.  Not sure how to access the `apache access log` on cpanel

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I've just checked the `php error log` again and I'm seeing these messages: `[Thu Oct 22 13:04:14.575567 2015] [:error] [pid 1041578] [client 74.125.76.51:56087] File does not exist: /home/fulldist/public_html/***.com/feed.php`, `[Thu Oct 22 09:53:14.646744 2015] [:error] [pid 944286] [client 31.13.113.90:59997] File does not exist: /home/fulldist/public_html/***.com/blog.php`.  It's true that `feed.php` and `blog.php` don't exist, but **why** is it trying to look them up?

Comment: I suppose that could just be a hack/probe attempt (_guessing_)

Comment: @RiggsFolly - So nothing to do with why I'm getting the 403 error then?  I did have files named `blog.php` and `feed.php` once, but the directroy has been deleted and re-set up sinse then with all new files added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forbidden Error 403 On Server Folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267392/forbidden-error-403-on-server-folder)

Answer (score 1):

Is this not wrong

```
header("Location: post.php?id=$id");
```

Dont you need this as a header

```
header("Location: posts/$id");
```

based on this rule

```
RewriteRule ^posts/([0-9]+)/?$              posts.php?currentpage=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```