# Strange Forbidden 403 Error - Solution Needed

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

I have a blog with a `add-post.php` page which contains a simple form with the action:

```
<form id="form" action="add-post-php.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I then have the file, `add-post-php.php` in the same folder as `add-post.php`.  So I enter the details of my blog into the form and press submit and get:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /add-post-php.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

- I've tested this on my localhost and it works correctly
- The permission of the file is set at 0644, but I've also tried it at 0755, with no improvement.
- There is nothing wrong with my .htaccess file and there are no other .htaccess files in the directory.
- I've tried using the full url path in my form `action`

My `add-post-php.php` script in full is:

```
<?php
include("php/settings.php"); // Contains DB Connections
?>
<?php
$id= time();
$month = date("m");
$year = date("Y");
$path = "images/posts/$year/$month/";

$section = $_POST["section"];
$category = $_POST["category"];
$credit = $_POST["credit"];
$title = ucwords($_POST["title"]);
$text = $_POST["text"];
$exclusive = $_POST["exclusive"];

$added = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$photo = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
$ext = substr(strrchr($photo, '.'), 1);
?>
<?php
$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO posts (id, section, category, credit, title, article, exclusive, added) VALUES('$id', '$section', '$category', '$credit', '$title', '$text', '$exclusive', '$added')";
$insert_res = mysqli_query($con, $insert_sql);
if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0){
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],"$path" . $id . "." . $ext);
}
else{
echo "0";
exit();
};
?>
<?php
header("Location: post.php?id=$id");
exit();
?>
```

Here is my .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex posts.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    

RewriteRule ^posts/([0-9]+)/?$              posts.php?currentpage=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^section/([\w-]+)/?$            section.php?section=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^section/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$   section.php?section=$1&currentpage=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^posts/([\w-]+)/?$              posts.php?category=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^posts/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$     posts.php?category=$1&currentpage=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)/?$      post.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^sites/([0-9]+)/?$              sites.php?currentpage=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^posts posts.php
RewriteRule ^section section.php
RewriteRule ^sites sites.php

RewriteRule ^about about.php
RewriteRule ^advertise advertise.php
RewriteRule ^subscribe subscribe.php
```

And folder structure:

[image]

I've checked the `php error log` and there's nothing suspicious there. Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting the Forbidden Error when the file clearly exists and it's permissions are correct?

Comment: Sorry @Epodax, that was a typing error, it's `add-post.php`

Comment: Your code is very prone to SQL Injection, make use of [parameter binding](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). Additionally, you may also want to validate your POST input using [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php), with appropriate flags.

Comment: I'm not concerned about SQL injection at the moment @HugoZink, The original script uses `mysqli_real_escape_string` but I've removed them temporarily while I get the problem at hand sorted out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forbidden Error 403 On Server Folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267392/forbidden-error-403-on-server-folder)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was with the `include` statement within the `add-post-php.php` file:

```
<?php
include("php/settings.php"); // Contains DB Connections
?>
```

I took this out and changed it to:

```
<?php
//Database Connect
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");
?>
```

The script worked as soon as I edited this line of code.