# Annoying Error 403 That Shouldn't Be Happening

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-403

I have a simple blog where I can add an article using a html form & php script, but I keep getting a 403 Error.  I'll provide all of my code:

**add-post.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="include/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form" action="http://website.com/add-post-php.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <li class="blockDate"><strong>Post Section</strong></li>
            <li class="blockText">
                <select id="section" name="section">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="blog">Blog Post</option>
                    <option value="news">News</option>
                    <option value="directory">Friends</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li class="blockDate">--</strong></li>
            <li class="blockDate"><strong>Post Categories</strong></li>
            <li class="blockText">
                <select id="category" name="category">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="posts">Posts</option>
                    <option value="reviews">Reviews</option>
                    <option value="">---</option>
                    <option value="news">News</option>
                    <option value="features">Features</option>
                    <option value="updates">Updates</option>
                    <option value="events">Events</option>
                    <option value="">---</option>
                    <option value="websites">Websites</option>
                    <option value="pro-models">Pro Models</option>
                    <option value="amateur-models">Amateur Models</option>
                    <option value="photographers">Photographers</option>
                    <option value="people">Participants</option>
                    <option value="businesses">Businesses</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li class="blockDate">--</strong></li>
            <li class="blockDate"><strong>Post Photo</strong></li>
            <li class="blockText"><input id="photo" name="photo" type="file" /></li>
            <li class="blockDate">--</strong></li>
            <li class="blockDate"><strong>Post Photo Credit</strong></li>
            <li class="blockText"><input type="text" id="credit" name="credit" /></li>
            <li class="blockDate">--</strong></li>
            <li class="blockDate"><strong>Post Title</strong></li>
            <li class="blockText"><input type="text" id="title" name="title" /></li>
            <li class="blockDate">--</strong></li>
            <li class="blockDate"><strong>Post Text</strong></li>
            <li class="blockText"><textarea id="text" name="text"></textarea></li>
            <li class="blockDate">--</strong></li>
            <li class="blockDate"><strong>Post Exclusive</strong></li>
            <li class="blockText">
                <select id="exclusive" name="exclusive">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="0">No</option>
                    <option value="1">Yes</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li class="blockDate">--</strong></li>
            <li class="blockDate">
                <input id="submitform" type="submit" value="Add This" />
            </li>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**add-post-php.php:**

```
<?php
//Database Connect
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","database");
?>
<?php
$id= time();
$month = date("m");
$year = date("Y");
$path = "images/posts/$year/$month/";

$section = stripslashes($_POST["section"]);
$category = stripslashes($_POST["category"]);
$credit = stripslashes($_POST["credit"]);
$title = stripslashes(ucwords($_POST["title"]));
$text = stripslashes($_POST["text"]);
$exclusive = stripslashes($_POST["exclusive"]);

$section = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $section);
$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $category);
$credit = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $credit);
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $title);
$text = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $text);
$exclusive = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $exclusive);

$added = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$photo = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
$ext = substr(strrchr($photo, '.'), 1);
?>
<?php
$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO posts (id, section, category, credit, title, article, exclusive, added) VALUES('$id', '$section', '$category', '$credit', '$title', '$text', '$exclusive', '$added')";
$insert_res = mysqli_query($con, $insert_sql);
if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0){
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],"$path" . $id . "." . $ext);
}
else{
echo "0";
exit();
};
?>
<?php
$url_title = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $title);
$url_title = strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$url_title));
?>
<?php
header("Location: post/$id/$url_title");
exit();
?>
```

So I add the details into my `add-post.php` form, which then gets sent to `add-post-php.php`.  The problem is that I'm getting an error 403 (Forbidden) when sending through to the PHP script, and I have no idea why.  I had a lot of trouble with it yesterday but surprisingly when I posted first thing this morning it worked fine.  2 minutes later when I added a second post I got the error again and it's been like that all day.  Can someone please help me with this?

**Folder:**

[image]

**.htaccess:**

```
Options -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex posts.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    

RewriteRule ^posts/([0-9]+)/?$              posts.php?currentpage=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^section/([\w-]+)/?$            section.php?section=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^section/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$   section.php?section=$1&currentpage=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^posts/([\w-]+)/?$              posts.php?category=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^posts/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$     posts.php?category=$1&currentpage=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)/?$      post.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^sites/([0-9]+)/?$              sites.php?currentpage=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^posts posts.php
RewriteRule ^section section.php
RewriteRule ^sites sites.php

RewriteRule ^about about.php
RewriteRule ^advertise advertise.php
RewriteRule ^subscribe subscribe.php
```

Comment: check rights of your directory. For example, you can set "chmod -R 777" (the simplest way), or you can set current user as owner of your directory. Generally, check if current user have write permissions.

Comment: especilly, check this path `$path = "images/posts/$year/$month/";`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forbidden Error 403 On Server Folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267392/forbidden-error-403-on-server-folder)